# Using a linear polarizing filter with a DSLR

Tags: dslr, polarizer

Can I use a linear polarizing filter with a DSLR camera in manual mode?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

However, linear polarizing filters can have some of the following implications for your camera:

- May affect in camera metering
- May affect auto-focus functionality
- May the low-pass filter in front of the sensor

For the first two issues you could meter externally, check the image histogram, and focus manually. If the last point is an issue for your particular camera, you'd have to switch to a circular filter.

*Links*
[The Complete Guide to Lens Filters (Part One)](http://wolfcrow.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-lens-filters-part-one/)
[What is the difference between a linear and a circular polarizer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/what-is-the-difference-between-a-linear-and-a-circular-polarizer?rq=1)
[Polarizing filter (photography) - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizing_filter_%28photography%29)